# Exception occured calling method NotesView.FTSearchSorted

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to use the FTSearchSorted method of the view object in the SSJS. I have the underlying view's first column sorted in ascending order. I tried with all different parameters. It always gives that exception, except when I only give the the search query as the parameter. The domino version is 8.5.3 FP 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: :) to figure that I had to try the FTSearchSorted method in java

Comment: Ah.  Sometimes that might not be enough either ;-)  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure the view is user sortable

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: how do you know that this is not the answer?

Comment: @ThomasAdrian: This answer is showing up in the Low Quality Posts queue because of how poor/vague/short it is. I recommend you improve your answer (such as by adding details on how to *check* "the view is user sortable"), or you're at risk of attracting negative comments/ downvotes. Alternately, you could/should consider moving this answer to a comment instead.

Comment: Hi Thomas Adrian, your answer is correct. Actually I had figured that out already and was going to post the solution myself. Anyways, thanks. The problem was that, the SSJS error message didn't provide enough details of the error. Then I tried the same in the java code and got the clue about what was wrong.

Comment: Rajeev, you can find more details on the SSJS error messages in the XPages log files on the server. For easy access use the XPages Log File Reader app available on OpenNTF.

Comment: In this case, there was no further details written to the xpages_exc_servername_2012_08_31@13_28_05 file

Comment: Actually the answer is valid + succinct if you are familiar with the product. Some level of expectation of usage of the product should be assumed unless the user says otherwise.

Comment: @ThomasAdrian I must not have had enough coffee yet, because I can't figure out whether "the view is user sortable" in my database. The first two columns are sorted, then I set another column "click to sort". Is that what we mean by user-sortable? It didn't work for me.

Comment: a view column is "user sortable" if a user can click a column to sort

Comment: I've expanded the details in Thomas's correct answer so that it is clearer.